# posicionar un div sobre todo el contenido bloqueando lo de abajo con CSS

Tags: html, css, div

tengo una consulta que no puedo resolver con CSS. Genere una App para carga de clientes con HTML y JQuey. Al subirlo al host, me encuentro con que al realizar click en el boton guardar por ejemplo, tiene delay en respuesta, y si se aproeta dos veces se genera una doble carga. Para solucionar esto hice un spinner con CSS, lo posiciono centrado sobre mi web, pero quiero que se posicione sobre todo el contenido para que n pueda manipularse nada hasta que finalice la carga... como puedo realizar este posicionamiento sobre todo el contenido y que me bloque lo que queda debajo.

Gracias!

Comment: tenes que agregar tu código, si copiamos y pegamos tu codigo en nuestros ide's es mas facil entender lo que esta mal y asi ayudarte mejor. Lee [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: si adicionas tu codigo podria ayudarte con mas facilidad, pero creo que colocando
tu spinner dentro de un div que tenga height: 100vh; position: fixed;, width: 100%, algun background-color con opacity, y z-index dependiendo de tus estilos ya funcionaria, ya que el contenedor ocuparia el 100% de la pantalla evitando hacer click fuera del mismo